# How to make Ubuntu server terminal have the same font and colour scheme as Ubuntu desktop's terminal?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, fonts

I am trying to make the terminal in Ubuntu server look and feel like the Ubuntu desktop terminal in terms of font and colour scheme. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes: SSH into it from your desktop.

Answer (score 4):

When you log in to a tty this is a login shell, so it sources, `~/.profile` or if it exists, `~/.bash_login` or if it exists,  `~/.bash_profile` (usually only `~/.profile` exists in Ubuntu).

`~/.bashrc` is sourced by interactive non-login shells (terminals you open in a desktop environment)

Here are aliases present by default in Ubuntu (desktop) for colours in terminals:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
```

These are found in `.bashrc` If they are not present, you can add them there.

To get the same settings as `.bashrc` in a login shell (tty) you should make sure that `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` or `.profile` is sourcing your `.bashrc` by putting something like this in your `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` or `.profile`, if it is not already there:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

The font is a different matter:

```
sudo apt install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console
```

Then add this line to the end of the same file (`.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or, most likely, `.profile`)

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/UbuntuMono-R-8x16.psf
```

To use it immediately, you can `source .profile` (or whichever file you put it in), otherwise, it will be changed on your next log in.

Answer (score 0):

All style and color stuff is related to your shell configuration. In the case of bash (Ubuntu standard) it is a simple file called .bashrc in your home folder. Copy it to the according folder (home folder of the user you are on the server) on the server and after reloading the shell it should be the same provided you do not need to install any further packages. Other shells are similar to bash, zsh e.g. uses a .zshrc.  In some cases you also have to copy more files if you did more advanced tweaks on your shells (e.g. .bash_aliases).