# Ubuntu desktop (gnome) terminal on ubuntu server?

Tags: command-line, server, gnome

I really like the terminal that comes with Ubuntu Desktop (I believe this is called gnome? Please correct me if I am mistaken).

Is there any way to install this into Ubuntu Server? The terminal in ubuntu server is not pleasing to the eye (I know I shouldn't care about the looks)

But if this is possible to do, I would like to know.

Thank you

edit: This may seem like the same question as some has pointed out. But they are different, I am just bad at explaining. I wanted to know if it was possible to install the gnome application into ubuntu server. My other question was how to make the ubuntu server have the same font/colour as ubuntu desktop. So one question was related to appearance, and the other was related to actually installing the gnome application itself.

Comment: You can only run gnome-terminal on a desktop, it is an application. You can't replace your TTY with it, they are not the same thing. Though you may like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/147462/how-can-i-change-the-tty-colors

Comment: reposted ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/813718/how-to-make-ubuntu-server-terminal-have-the-same-font-and-colour-scheme-as-ubunt/813837#813837

Comment: @Zanna Indeed, I don't think it is intentionally the same question but they are very related and the answers would be the same. I voted it as a dupe.

Comment: @Zanna @ Mark Kirby   Please see my edit regarding that this is a separate question to my other question. Thanks.

Comment: One of the simple way is to take "ssh user@ServerIPaddress of server from Ubuntu Desktop and you get the same gnome-terminal feel (such as same font / colour ) !.

Answer (score 2):

You can only run `gnome-terminal` on a desktop, it is an application. You can't replace your TTY with it, they are not the same thing, you can't have a gtk application without a window manager to run it in.

I refer you to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813718/how-to-make-ubuntu-server-terminal-have-the-same-font-and-colour-scheme-as-ubunt/813837#813837) on your last question, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701874/how-can-i-customize-a-full-screen-console-background-tty) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147462/how-can-i-change-the-tty-colors) from my comment.

If you want `gnome-terminal` you need a desktop but those links combined should help you get almost there.

Comment: Well, you could install just and xserver (xorg) and a minimal window manager like BlackBox to run graphical applications, rather than a full DE.

Comment: @Zanna good point :)

Comment: I was writing my own version of the same thing, but have an upvote instead of a 'competitor' :)